# How to Properly Migrate SQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql, export

If I am changing servers, I usually migrate my wordpress database by going to phpmyadmin and doing an SQL Export on one server and doing an Import on the other server.

I notice that in this process, some times my data gets malformed.

For example, " : ' ~ ...  etc, these characters may turn into weird stuff like â€šÃ‚Â

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you're using the same encoding/collation in the source and destination database servers. If you're not specifying anything in particular you could be getting the default treatment on both, and that could be Latin-1 in one and UTF-8 in the other - specially if the distributions are different.

Also check that the Wordpress settings are the same in the source and destination. This may come in handy: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-convert-character-set-and-collation-of-wordpress-database/.